# Wordpress 403 error when moved site to another host

Tags: wordpress, restore, http-status-code-403

I restored my files and database to new hosting. But when I try to access [my blog](http://blog.hfarazm.com/) I get the following error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Its been 6 days now I have been trying to fix this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it was this line in .htaccess (it selects the php version to be used):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

I just comment it out and it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your wp-config.php file.  Make sure that everything points to the new hosting addresses and logins and nothing refers to the old hosting.

Also be sure that there are no cached files you're transferring over through FTP.

Lastly once the site resolves the 403, be sure your CSS files (depending on what plugins you're using) all point to the proper path of your new hosting.